# Printing Odd Even number sequentially using two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not able to understand why below program is not working in odd even scenario.

Output I am getting is `In Odd Thread 1`

The program execution if I understand-

Goes to t1 thread. Condition not satisfied. Calls notifyAll which goes unnoticed.Goes to t2 thread, which prints odd number increments and calls wait(). T2 should begin operation in this case right??

```
public class OddEvenTest {

    static int max = 20;
    static int count = 1;
    static Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    while(count % 2  == 0 && count < max) {
                        System.out.println("In even Thread " +count);
                        count++;
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            while(count % 2  != 0 && count < max) {
                                System.out.println("In Odd Thread " +count);
                                count++;
                                try {
                                    lock.wait();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }               
                            }
                            lock.notifyAll();
                        }

                    }
                });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to blindly `wait()` in a loop synchronized on your `lock`. Instead, check your pre-conditions for `wait`ing, like

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (count < max) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("In Even Thread " + count);
                    count++;
                    lock.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (count < max) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (count % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println("In Odd Thread " + count);
                    count++;
                    lock.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In Java 8+, you can simplify your anonymous classes with lambdas like

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    while (count < max) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("In Even Thread " + count);
                count++;
                lock.notifyAll();
            } else {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    while (count < max) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (count % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("In Odd Thread " + count);
                count++;
                lock.notifyAll();
            } else {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If I try to understand this. We start t1 and t2 , suppose the scheduler picks t1, it goes to else block, calls wait() , releases the lock. t2 is picked, 1 is printed, and notify() is called. But, notify doesn't release lock . right?? I am really confused here. Could you  please let me know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: [`Object.notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()) says *The awakened threads will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object* - when does the current thread relinquish the lock? Immediately after the `synchronized(lock)` block... which is to say right after `notifyAll()`.

Comment: Got it . So if t1 starts first, t1 will call `wait()` as the condition is not met , releases the lock. t2 prints 1, calls `notifyAll(),` execution goes to t1, prints 2 calls `notifyAll() `which goes un answered as t2 is not in waiting state. `Wait() ` would be called only the first time. Is that correct. Will there be a scenario where the `wait()` could be called at later stage.?

Comment: `wait` will be called whenever `count < max` and the `count % 2` test doesn't meet the precondition; notice that the thread will block until it can enter the `synchronized` block. The `synchronized` block is what holds the monitor on the `lock`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems i can think of

1. notifyAll has been written outside the loop so think about a scenario where odd thread is getting executed and printed the value and it is about to call wait but even thread has called notify before odd thread call wait so odd thread will always be in waiting state. So you should keep notifyAll inside loop. 
   This is something you have experienced in your execution.
2. while loop should keep executing till count is less than max and the even or condition should be applied inside while loop.
3. wait should go in else condition

#### Refactored Code

```
public class OddEvenTest {

  static int max = 20;
  static int count = 1;
  static Object lock = new Object();

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
          while(count < max) {
            if(count % 2  == 0 ) {
              System.out.println("In even Thread " + count);
              count++;
            }else{
              try {
                lock.wait();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }
            lock.notifyAll();
          }
        }
      }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
          while(count < max) {
            if(count % 2  != 0) {
              System.out.println("In Odd Thread " + count);
              count++;
            }else{
              try {
                lock.wait();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              }
            }
            lock.notifyAll();
          }
        }

      }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

  }
}
```